# find only the first file from many directories

Tags: bash, unix, awk, command-line, find

I have a lot of directories:

```
13R
613
AB1
ACT
AMB
ANI
```

Each directories contains a lots of file:

```
20140828.13R.file.csv.gz
20140829.13R.file.csv.gz
20140830.13R.file.csv.gz
20140831.13R.file.csv.gz
20140901.13R.file.csv.gz

20131114.613.file.csv.gz
20131115.613.file.csv.gz
20131116.613.file.csv.gz
20131117.613.file.csv.gz

20141114.ab1.file.csv.gz
20141115.ab1.file.csv.gz
20141116.ab1.file.csv.gz
20141117.ab1.file.csv.gz

etc..
```

The purpose if to have the first file from each directories

The result what I expect is:

```
13R|20140828
613|20131114
AB1|20141114
```

Which is the name of the directories pipe the date from the filename.
I guess I need a find and head command + awk but I can't make it, I need your help.

Here what I have test it

```
for f in $(ls -1);do ls -1 $f/ | head -1;done
```

But the folder name is missing.

When I mean the first file, is the first file returned in an alphabetical order within the folder.

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code, any code, it doesn't have to be perfect. You sense to use `find,head,awk` is very close to a good idea. So add some code and people will help you fix it. Also, while you show your required output, what is the actual "rule" you are using for the "first file" in the directory? First sorted by name, or the first file created in the directory (becuase the creation date isn't kept in Unix file system). Please update your Q with that critical piece of information. Good luck.

Comment: Also, what do you exactly mean by first file?

Comment: pluse uno for adding some code and letting us know what you mean about "first file". Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a Bash loop.

Given:

```
/tmp/test
/tmp/test/dir_1
/tmp/test/dir_1/file_1
/tmp/test/dir_1/file_2
/tmp/test/dir_1/file_3
/tmp/test/dir_2
/tmp/test/dir_2/file_1
/tmp/test/dir_2/file_2
/tmp/test/dir_2/file_3
/tmp/test/dir_3
/tmp/test/dir_3/file_1
/tmp/test/dir_3/file_2
/tmp/test/dir_3/file_3
/tmp/test/file_1
/tmp/test/file_2
/tmp/test/file_3
```

Just loop through the directories and form an array from a glob and grab the first one:

```
prefix="/tmp/test"
cd "$prefix"
for fn in dir_*; do 
    cd "$prefix"/"$fn"
    arr=(*)
    echo "$fn|${arr[0]}"
done
```

Prints:

```
dir_1|file_1
dir_2|file_1
dir_3|file_1
```

If your definition of 'first' is different that Bash's, just sort the array `arr` according to your definition before taking the first element.

---

You can also do this with `find` and `awk`:

```
$ find /tmp/test -mindepth 2 -print0 | awk -v RS="\0" '{s=$0; sub(/[^/]+$/,"",s); if (s in paths) next; paths[s]; print $0}'
/tmp/test/dir_1/file_1
/tmp/test/dir_2/file_1
/tmp/test/dir_3/file_1
```

And insert a `sort` (or use `gawk`) to sort as desired

Answer (score 2):

`sort` has an unique option. Only the directory should be unique, so use the first field in sorting `-k1,1`. The solution works when the list of files is sorted already.

```
printf "%s\n" */* | sort -k1,1 -t/ -u | sed 's#\(.*\)/\([0-9]*\).*#\1|\2#'
```

You will need to change the `sed` command when the date field may be followed by another number.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
for dir in $(find "$FOLDER" -type d); do
  FILE=$(ls -1 -p $dir | grep -v / | head -n1)
  if [ ! -z "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "$dir/$FILE"
  fi
done
```